# Xamarin XAML: Type is not found from external assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I have a `Visual Studio` solution, which has 2 C# projects:

1. a C# portable `BasicLib`;
2. a C# portable `XAML project`.

I defined resource files and a public `LocalizedStrings` class in the `BasicLib`. Its namespace is "`PL.Common.BasicLib`", the assembly name is "`PL.Common.BasicLib.dll`".

**LocalizedStrings.cs**

```
namespace PL.Common.BasicLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to string resources.
    /// </summary>
    public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();

        public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
    }
}
```

Then I add reference from the XAML project to this `PL.Common.BasicLib`. So far so good. I double click the assembly name from the XAML project's "`References`" node, I can see the Type "`LocalizedStrings`" under the "`PL.Common.BasicLib`" in the Visual Studio's "`Object Browser`".

Now, I would like to put this resource into `App.xaml` as application resource in this way:

**App.xaml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:basiclib="clr-namespace:PL.Common.BasicLib;assembly=PL.Common.BasicLib"
             x:Class="PL.Common.Xaml.App">

  <Application.Resources>
    <basiclib:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Build the solution, no problem. When running it, there will throw an error:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:6. 
Type basiclib:LocalizedStrings not found in xmlns clr-namespace:PL.Common.BasicLib;assembly=PL.Common.BasicLib
```

Can someone help to take a look where is the bug?

thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate why you want the structure you do? Normally, you would place your localised resources in the `PCL` of your `Xamarin.Forms` project.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you by any chance resolve this?

Comment: did you get any solution for this error? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Just ran into it now.  I can confirm that adding a reference in the code behind seems to solve the issue.  It appears that the assemblies are being optimized out of the executable if the references only appear in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to a known linking issue - where Xamarin compiler ends up linking out classes (from external assemblies) that have references only in XAML.

There are couple of links that talk about this:

1. [Extending Control plugins](https://blog.xamarin.com/extending-xamarin-forms-with-control-plugins/#GettingStarted) > Getting Started
2. [Force assembly linking](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=242)

There are a lot of options to resolve this:

1. Add a static Init method in each class as mentioned here in "Getting started" section [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/extending-xamarin-forms-with-control-plugins/#GettingStarted)

   ```
   // this ensures the class does not get 
   // linked out in the application we add this assembly to.
   public static void Init() { }
   ```
2. Or, preserve code using preserve attributes on [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Preserving_Code), and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/#Preserving_Code)

   ```
   public class Example
   {
        [Android.Runtime.Preserve]
        public Example ()
        {
        }
   }
   ```
3. Or, use [Custom linking](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/).
4. Or, update project configuration to not link. [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#Linker_Behavior), and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/#Linker_Behavior). Not a recommended option though.

Comment: This is a serious issue.  I've just run into it also.  Any idea where I can report this to someone who cares?